# Azure Scheduler with Azure SQL Server (as local)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-scheduler

**Before marking as duplicate**, note that I'm not asking how to create a Scheduler in Azure or how to work with Azure SQL Server!

I have a task that I need to run every day, and that task communicates with a database that is hosted in Azure. I assume that the task will be hosted on the same machine (**or will it?** how can I make sure it does?), so the communication with the database will be local and therefore much faster (great).
But I'm not entirely sure how to define the connection.

Currently, as my task is not yet hosted in Azure, I'm using a standard connection string to connect to the database hosted on Azure. Need I change the connection string if I host it in Azure (to make sure it'll be considered local), or will it be automagically as fast as a local storage? If I do need to change the connection string, **what would be the connection string?**

Is it possible to host the code (as an exe, or anything else) locally besides the database for faster access?

Comment: is that an Azure SQL Server VM or an Azure SQL Database?

Comment: @JuneT It's an Azure SQL Database. At this point it is more urgent to schedule the exe appropriately even if the database-communication isn't local, if that's any simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's an Azure SQL Database, you don't really get much access to the underlying server itself.

you are using database as a service. so you can't install/upload an executable on the server hosting your database itself. Azure SQL doesnt support CLR either unlike SQL Server.

If you have a simple executable that you want to execute on schedule, the easiest would be to deploy it on Azure Website in the same DC as your Azure SQL and have your executable scheduled and execute via WebJobs. see: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Comment: Ok, so I understand you can't really make it local, which kinda sucks. Anyways, managed to get it working as a WebJob so good enough :D